# Truncating part of an LDAP DN in Powershell? (Or getting the OU from an LDAP DN.)

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-v4.0

What's the easiest way to get the OU containing an LDAP object in PowerShell?

I'm working on a script to manage some groups that I've made "dynamic" with a script, and I can get the full distinguished name with the below:

```
$PseudoDynamicGroupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like $PseudoDynamicGroup}).DistinguishedName
```

It returns something like:

```
CN=MyPseudoDynamicGroup,OU=Users,OU=BusinessUnit,OU=Site,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=forest,DC=tld
```

And I'm looking to discard the `CN=MyPseudoDynamicGroup,` bit so I end up with:

```
OU=Users,OU=BusinessUnit,OU=Site,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=forest,DC=tld
```

How do I do this as easily as possible?  I tried using the [Split operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but this returns an array, and strips out the commas, forcing me to add them back in.  I suspect there's a better way.

Comment: Note: I self-answered, but am also interested in other solutions, so I'm going to leave it unaccepted for a while to give others a chance to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I've found so far is to use the [.NET framework IndexOf method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d93tkzah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the index of the first instance of the comma character, and feed that to the [.NET framework Substring method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I used the code below, which puts the desired string into a variable named `PseudoDynamicGroupOU`.

```
$PseudoDynamicGroupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like $PseudoDynamicGroup}).DistinguishedName;
$PseudoDynamicGroupDNPosition = $PseudoDynamicGroupDN.IndexOf(",");
$PseudoDynamicGroupOU = $PseudoDynamicGroupDN.Substring($PseudoDynamicGroupDNPosition+1);
```